# Github pages: Jekyll changes not showing in _site

Tags: git, github, jekyll, github-pages

I just set up my Jekyll site on Github pages, and the whole site works fine when going to the Pages url, new posts appear correctly etc. However my _site folder isn't showing any changes when viewing the repository via Github.

Does Github pages generate the site into _site on the same repository and then serve _site at the url? 
The idea is that I would use Github pages for a kind of staging server, so I do my new posts in Prose.io, then make sure all is working by checking the Github pages url, then pull down the _site folder contents into my own server. 
I have it all set up and running correctly, its just when i pull down there arent any new changes in the _site folder despite those changing being shown on the Pages url.

Answer (score 1):

Github generates your site for your, so it's useless to push your `_site` folder.

Now you can still :

1. Edit with prose on your github page
2. test the result
3. pull your changes from github to your local
4. make a jekyll build locally
5. push to your own server

Comment: Ah ok, I guess that makes sense. Was hoping to get an almost fully automated process going, without having to install jekyll locally - for the sake of other people wanting to publish content. Thanks